# bash script; searching files for threshold value in table by row and print out to file or stdout

Tags: bash

Linux newbe;

I have a dir containing >100 dirs each having a file with similar content.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 Final Restraint Analysis for coords: md.rst


 Restraints, deviations, and energy contributions:    pencut =   -0.00

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     First atom        Last atom    curr. value target deviation  penalty
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *H43  BOC    1 --  H    ALA    2:    4.506    4.760    0.000    0.000 d    0: 0
```

in these files there are following rows like the last one. I need to search each line for the column penalty for a threshold and if it is greater than this line should be printed to stdout or to a file.
I started by using cut but struggle with the delimiter and even if I would have cut the correct coulmn I don't know how to save the line number and print this line to file or stdout.

Thx for your help

Comment: Is it possible change format of your files to csv? If columns are multiple space delimited, is this work? `cat your_file | tr -s ' ' ',' | cut -d"," -f 12`

Comment: With your example file above, I can imagine passing it through `cat -n` to get line numbers.  Then pipe it through `sed` to convert multiple runs of spaces and tabs into a single space. Then pipe that through `cut` to pull out the line number and value you seek.

Comment: `cat your_file | tr -s ' ' ',' | cut -d"," -f 12 | sed '/^\s*$/d' `                                works so far and limited the file for the column of values where the threshhold needs to be checked.                                   also `cat -n ` workes and adds line numbers. However I don't know how to combine these things. So how to print out lines with this 'value < threshold' as argument line by line

Comment: I might have found a way to solve but still it is not 100% working    <br/>     `for i in folder_*; do `  `while read line; do`  `x= echo "$line" | tr -s ' ' ',' | cut -d"," -f 11`   `if $x > 5  then  echo "$line";  fi  done < input_file`   However since not every line contains x.xxx it also gives back blanks and "---". and the if clause does not work. I thought of rounding by piping x through `| printf "%.*f\n" 0` however this only gives 0 all the time. In shell `printf "%.*f\n" 0 5.555` works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a lot of help I finally have a solution:

```
#! /bin/bash
cutoff=5.0
for i in sim_results_rep*; do

while read -r LINE; do
echo $LINE | grep 'First atom' > /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  continue 
else
 read -r LINE 
    while true; do 
      read -r LINE
      echo $LINE | grep 'Total distance penalty' > /dev/null
      if [ $? -ne 0 ] 
      then
       x=`echo "$LINE" | awk '{print $11}'` 
    if [ `echo "$x > $cutoff" | bc` == 1 ] 
    then
      echo "In file $i, the follwing distance has a penalty higher than $cutoff"
      echo $LINE
    else
      continue 

    fi

  else 
    break
    fi

  done
  break 
fi

done < $i/*.nmrout

done
```